# Smallest field and root of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, roots-of-unity, primitive-roots

I'm trying to solve the following:

> Let $K$ be the smallest field, with characteristic $2$ such that it contains a $15$-primitive root of the unit. Find its cardinality and a primitive element of such a field.

I know that a $15-$th root of unity is contained in such a field if $$15|q-1$$ where $q$ is the cardinality of the field. Now I should use the condition $\chi(K)=2$, but I really don't know how. I mean, how can use it?

I would be tempted to say $q = 2^n$, but does this really imply that the characteristic is $2$? I just know $F_2$ as field with such a char, it seems wrong to me actually.

Once I get what is the field, it's just a matter of computation to find the primitive element.

Comment: a finite field with characteristic $2$ has cardinality $2^n$ (it's an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb F_2$)

Comment: You need to find the least power of $2$ that is $\equiv1\pmod{15}$,

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh yes, my bad. So, I'm searching for the smallest $n$ such that $$15|2^n - 1 $$,i .e. $n=4$. Therefore, such a field is $\mathbb{F}_{16}$, which has $16$ elements, and a primitive element is given by $\bar{x}$, the coset $ x + (x^4+x+1)$, given by the construction of $F_{16}$ as quotient $F_2[x] /(x^4 + x +1)$.

Is

Comment: @J.W.Tanner could you confirm what I wrote? It seems right now

Comment: It seems right now